# Storing cooked potatoes in the fridge

Tags: storage-method

So I read that storing raw potatoes in the fridge causes the starch to turn to sugar (which I don't want). So I store them in the pantry shelf. But what about cooked potatoes? Will storing them in the fridge cause the starch to turn into sugar?

Comment: Once they are cooked, the general rules of food safety apply as outlined in our [generic post](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer). Put your cooked potatoes in the fridge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The advice for storing raw potatoes is because they are still "alive" in a sense.

By storing them in the cold, you are telling them it is winter and they should be converting their stored starch into sugar so they can grow in the spring.

Once you've cooked them, that's no longer a problem - you've killed them, so the conversion isn't going to happen any more.  General food safety rules would then apply.